# Java Play 2 authentication - > mongoDB

Tags: java, authentication, mongodb, playframework-2.0, morphia

Today I stumbled over https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate . I looks absolutely amazing. For me it's very difficult to understand whats going on and I probably need several days.

Now this plugin is written for sql, but we want to use nosql (mongoDB).

**But before I start I want to ask you if you could give me a brief overview of what I have to change?**

I am asking because I need to change quite a lot and I don't want to make a huge mistake at the beginning just to see that I only had to change the config file.

---

Example:

I would have started like this:

```
private static ExpressionList<User> getEmailUserFind(final String email) {
    return find.where().eq("active", true).eq("email", email);
}
```

I would replace this code with Morphia

for example

```
//pseudo code
private static ExpressionList<User> getEmailUserFind(final String email) {
        return datastore.createQuery(Some.class).field("active").equal("true").field("email").equal(email)...

    }
```

Comment: Although can't help you with morphia, there's suggest, when you'll finish it, please create next sample for Play Authenticate + MongoDB and publish it somehow :)

Comment: Your general approach of replacing the relational syntax with Morphia equivalents seems fine.  I think it would be worth trying to contact the original `play authenticate` author to see if he's thought about NoSQL and would be interested if you made this a configurable option.  Looks like you've already added an [issue on Github](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/issues/17), but perhaps could use more details on your intended implementation.